# How do I call a Service from my $httpProvider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I've been struggling with this all morning. I'm trying to call a Service from within my config($httpprovider). I've read a lot of people explaining that Services are not yet available during config. I get that, but my service should only be called from within the interceptor, which is at runtime.

I found a semi-solution that manually injected the Service manually like below, but it's not working for me, since it seems a completely new instance of the Service is being created, and I want to keep using the same instance throughout the app (since it stores a messageQueue array). Any suggestions?

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
            return {
                'responseError': function (rejection) {
                    //responses 300 and up are errors
                    //Manually inject service from the myServices module, since it is not yet known when .config is called
                    var $injector = window.angular.injector(['myServices']);
                    var MessageService = $injector.get('MessageService');
                    MessageService.setMessage("We were unable to load all necessary data. We're terribly sorry! Please try reloading this page or contact us if the problem isn't solved.");
                }
            };
        });
    }])
```

Comment: why do you need the service in the $httpprovider? maybe there's another way to solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can register your interceptor as a service using a factory, according to [angularjs 1.2.2 documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/docs/api/ng.$http), so it should be provided with the right dependencies, using the following syntax :

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {

    $provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', ['MessageService', function (MessageService) {
        return {
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                //responses 300 and up are errors
                MessageService.setMessage("We were unable to load all necessary data. We're terribly sorry! Please try reloading this page or contact us if the problem isn't solved.");
            }
        };
    }]);

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
}]);
```